# Adding new styles to stylesheet not working in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a ROR app. It has a `style.css` stylesheet in its `public/scaffold_files` folder. I can see the style reference to this file when I inspect the elements. But now I want to change/add some styles. Any changes I make to this file is not affected in the view. **How do we add new styles??** I dont want to use the `<style>` tag and write code in the view itself, I want it in a stylesheet.
PS: this `style.css` file is referred in the `layout` file as below and I can see the same when I do 'view page source'.

```
  <link href="/scaffold_files/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: try : clear browser `cache?` check: in View Page Source the style.css is loaded?

Comment: read `rails getting started` guide once again and save the world

Comment: Yeah the style.css is loaded.. it shows the styling for all elements from there

Comment: I dont want to use the <style> tag and write code in the view itself is called `inline styling`. solution dig deeper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails asset pipeline is broken up into 3 different sections.

- app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, usually scripted by yourself.
- lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit
  into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared
  across applications.
- vendor/assets is for assets that are 3rd party, such as js plugins and frameworks.

It is generally bad practise to start adding assets in the public folder. When your asset pipeline tries to compile and compress them in production, it won't be able to find them because it only looks in the app, lib and vendor folders.

To get started, just create a file called 'application.css' within the app/assets folder. Then reference this file within your layout (layout/application.html.erb) using the following syntax:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

This will automatically look in the app/assets folder, and retrieve, the file named 'application'. Thereby rendering new styles within your applcation!

If you need further help with assets, check out the RailsGuides; they have alot of helpful and in depth content.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks JellyFishBoy.. I dint create a new style sheet but added this to my layout file <%= stylesheet_link_tag :style%>.. I copied my style.css from public to app/assets and referred it.. Now it works :)