# Adding a javascript file to my assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with the following namespace

```
view/kids/registration/new.html.haml
```

Now I need to create a js file to this view, so I created a file in the following path:

```
assets/javascripts/kids/registration/new.js
```

Then I add the following lines to the application.js:

```
//= require ./kids/registrations/new
```

But it does not work. What I'm doing wrong. I'm checking the DOM (localhost:3000/kids/sign_up) but I never find line with this javascript file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Adding the route

```
new_kid_registration GET /kids/sign_up(.:format) frontend/registrations#new
```

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571753/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-how-to-load-controller-specific-scripts

Comment: did this get solved??

Answer (score 1):

Try `//= require kids/registrations/new` or `//= require kids/registrations/new.js`

Comment: It doesn't work Bob. I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problems while adding  stylesheets to assets ([Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264598/adding-new-styles-to-stylesheet-not-working-in-rails))

Here are few things you might wanna try:

- As suggested by BOB add the require statements to application.js
- I remember adding the list of files to `application.rb` as:

  ```
     config.assets.precompile += ['jquery.colorbox.js','colorbox.css', 'reportng.css', 'reportng.js']
  ```
- Your JS file can be placed anywhere in lib/assets/javascripts,
  assets//assets/javascripts & vendor/assets/javascripts
- Try using the
  `<%= javascript_include_tag "your_js_file_name" %>` in your view file